# "Unable to parse class file" ear deployment issue weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy an ear file in weblogic 12 but it gives the following error while trying to deploy the ear:

```
<Error> <J2EE> <BEA-160248> <Unable to parse class file: zip:D:/Weblogic/user_projects/domains/..../tmp/.appmergegen_1/lib/log4j-api-2.9.0.jar!/META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ProcessIdUtil.class.

<Error> <J2EE> <BEA-160248> <Unable to parse class file: zip:D:/Weblogic/user_projects/domains/...../tmp/.appmergegen_1/lib/log4j-api-2.9.0.jar!/META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator.class.
```

I have built the project using java 1.8.0_121.Also have placed the log4j-api-2.9.0 in lib of the server.

Answer (score 2):

The `log4j-api-2.9.0.jar` is a multiple release jar. This feature was added from JDK9. The java 8 which is present in your environment does not support it, therefore these files can not be parsed and WebLogic reports BEA-160248.

The https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#Backward_Compatibility states that

> The new class loading scheme is totally backward compatible with applications developed on top of the current extension mechanism. When the class loader loads the first jar file and an INDEX.LIST file is found in the META-INF directory, it would construct the index hash table and use the new loading scheme for the extension. Otherwise, the class loader will simply use the original linear search algorithm.

and according to the Doc ID 2629550.1

> This message is harmless and can be ignored.

Answer (score -2):

You should built the project using java 1.7. Weblogic support Java EE 7 for now.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19895311)

Comment: This is my personal experience and I put it into practice in order to find the answer